# MYSQL query not returning proper set of rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
table_subcategories - sub_categories_id, sub_category_name, sub_category_image_path
table_subcategory_categories - subcategory_id, category_id
```

I want to get all the subcategories from table_subcategories for which there is no mapping entry present in  "table_subcategory_categories" with given category_id

I am using this query, but result is not correct.

```
my $sql_query = "SELECT  TSC.sub_categories_id, TSC.sub_category_name, TSC.sub_category_image_path  from table_subcategories as TSC 
INNER JOIN
table_subcategory_categories as TSCC
ON
TSC.sub_categories_id = TSCC.subcategory_id
WHERE
TSCC.category_id != $cId ";
```

Can please some one help me to get what is wrong in this?

Comment: table 1 means table_subcategories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join` and check for no matches:

```
SELECT TSC.* 
from table_subcategories TSC LEFT JOIN
     table_subcategory_categories  TSCC
     ON TSC.sub_categories_id = TSCC.subcategory_id AND
        TSCC.Category_Id = $cId
WHERE TSCC.category_id IS NULL;
```